# Send ctrl-alt-del over minicom

Tags: unix, putty, serial

Is there a way to send key combos (namely a sysrq) over minicom? I'm looking to issue ctrl-alt-del to a box of mine so I can shut it down gracefully. Does this exist?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302205/how-to-send-sysrq-command-over-ssh-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial line doesn't send the same key events as a keyboard does. It mostly sends text, with some special codes here and there. Many special keys are represented as sequences starting with ESC – but not all of them. There are no sequences for such keys as SysRq, for example, and there is no generic "Ctrl key being held" code – letters have one way of indicating Ctrl, arrow keys have another, some other codes can't indicate it at all.

You **can** trigger the Linux "Magic SysRq" if your serial terminal software supports sending a 'Break' signal. For example, the equivalent of Alt+SysRq+S is [Break] followed by S alone.

However, Ctrl+Alt+Del **is not** a "SysRq" key combo, and there doesn't appear to be any SysRq-key alternative to it. (Alt+SysRq is the opposite – a very immediate reboot that doesn't even flush filesystems, much less cleanly stop services.)

Comment: FYI, if you can't get it working with `minicom`, `miniterm` (sometimes spelled `pyserial-miniterm` or `miniterm.py` by some packagers) is a handy tool included in the `pyserial` package (see `pypi.org`).  It supports activating a serial [break condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter#Break_condition) using ctl-t,ctl-b (then deactivate it whenever you like with the same allowing you to contol the duration of the break).  You can also do the same from python code you can write yourself (using `class Serial` defined in the `pyserial` package).

Comment: @Juan: Personally I never got used to minicom at all – I find `tio` or `picocom` easier to use, and those also have similarly convenient 'break' shortcuts (although usually fixed pulse, not on/off toggle).